# promise inside factory, return before promise is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory, `areaFactory` and inside it I have this:

```
return {
    GetAreas : function(depKey){
        var areaPromise = AppService.getArea(depKey);
        areaPromise.then(function (Obj){
            var areas = Obj['rows'];
            var areaList = [];

            angular.forEach(areas, function(obj){
                areaList.push({
                    id: obj[0],
                    name: obj[1]
                });
            });

            return areaList;

        });
    }
}
```

When I call `$scope.areas = AreaFactory.GetAreas(key);` from a controller `$scope.areas` becomes undefined, and I figured it is because my factory returns `undefined` before my promise is done.

How can I make the factory wait until the promise is done, before it returns the list of areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the promise from the factory method:

```
GetAreas : function(depKey){
        var areaPromise = AppService.getArea(depKey);
        return areaPromise.then(function (Obj){
              ....
        });
}
```

And then in the controller:

```
AreaFactory.GetAreas(key).then(function(list){
    $scope.areas = list;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast, workable solution! Now I can go to lunch happy, I will accept when I get back (7min until I can accept, due to 10min rule)

Answer (score 0):

When you return the promise, make sure that you handle error cases in your controller.
For example:

```
AreaFactory.GetAreas(key).then(
  function(list){
    $scope.areas = list;
  },
  function(error) {
    //handle error here
  }
);
```